# Resize window without covering widget

Tags: tkinter, resize, pack

This Python-tkinter program uses the pack geometry manager to place a text widget and a "quit" button in the root window -- the text widget is above the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root, height=5, width=25, bg='lightblue')
txt.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
txt.insert('1.0', 'this is a Text widget')
tk.Button(root, text='quit', command=quit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I resize the root window by dragging its lower border up, I lose the quit button. It vanishes under the root window's border. But I'm trying to get the quit button to move up along with the window's border, while letting the text widget shrink. I have played with "fill" and "expand" in pack() and "height" in both widgets without success.

Is there any straightforward way to keep the quit button visible while dragging the window smaller?

(While researching, I noticed that grid geometry with its "sticky" cells can accomplish this task easily. But I'm still curious to know if there is any simple way to do the same with pack geometry.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pack the quit button before packing the text widget. When the window is too small for its contents it starts to shrink widgets in the reverse order tat they were packed until it can't shrink anymore, then it starts clipping widgets.

The text widget, being the largest widget in your window, can shrink a lot before it starts getting clipped.

Comment: Great. That's as simple and straightforward as I could hope for, and it behaves exactly as I want.

For the sake of someone coming along later: since I am now packing the button _before_ I pack the text, but I still want the button to appear _after_ the text, I need to use "pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)" for packing the button.